# Comparing multiple attributes in single If statements - Yaml configs

Tags: if-statement, yaml

Am working on a code part that requires composite parameters comparision for each else if logic, just like

```
if [switch] == "false" {
  }
}

 else if [switch] == "true" & [param] == "a" {
   }

} 
else if [switch] == "true" & [param] == "b" { }
```

Can some one help if there is a sample snippet to refer

composite else statement